# How to share the link of an app if i don't know what URL it will have

Tags: android, share

How to implement "share app" button if i still don't know what URL the app will have in play store (the app hasn't been released yet).

Comment: which OS are you developing in?

Comment: android (very good quistion, my bad)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Every play store app URL contain app package name. So if your application package name is `com.yourappname` then your play store URL is like this.

```
https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.yourappname
```

I hope this will help you.

Comment: Thank you for your time.

Comment: Sorry for the delay, I wanted to try if it works in Google Play. It worked. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

It's better to use

```
context.getPackageName()
```

You can use `market://` protocol to open the app in play store app.
But mind it, this will crash the app if play store is not installed.

You can use the following :

```
final String appPackageName = getPackageName(); // Use this method to get the package name. Instead of hard coding it.
try {
    startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("market://details?id=" + appPackageName)));
} catch (android.content.ActivityNotFoundException anfe) {
    startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("http://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=" + appPackageName)));
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your time.

Comment: You can accept this as answer if this helped and close the question.

Answer (score 0):

An easy, if inelegant, solution is to just not have the "share app" button in your first release on Day 1. Once you know the URL of your app's appstore entry, you can add the "share app" feature and upload and release version 1.1 or 1.0.1 of your app on Day 2.

ETE: To give your problem some context: If you think you need the "share app" feature on Day 1 because you're going to have a million downloads on Day 1, then do you really need the "share app" feature? If you think you're only going to have a handful of downloads on Day 1, then not having that feature available on Day 1 probably isn't going to make or break your app.

See also: [MVP, minimum viable product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minimum_viable_product).

Comment: Thank you for your time.